# How to use a button in VBA Excel to copy a row, and paste to a new sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I have tried searching other questions, I have found similar ones for pasting to the next row on a new sheet, but I can never get them to work.

What I am making is an inventory tracking sheet. "Current Inventory" is where the inventory is entered. Then I have "History 5440" where I want to create a history of each week for a Dell Latitude 5440 laptop.

What I want to happen is when you are done entering the current inventory, you click the Submit button and have it find the 5440 item (A8) and copy the input which is in B8:G8. Once copied, have it pasted to the next available row in "History 5440" starting in Column B.

I have the button also configured to send an email of the current inventory, which works just fine.

Let me know if I can provide any more info. Thanks for the help!!

```
Sub Copy5440s()

' Copy5440s Macro
' Copys the 5440 info and pastes it to the next available row in History 5440.

Range("B8:G8").Copy
NextRow = Sheets("History 5440").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
Sheets("History 5440").Paste

End Sub
```

---

So I have things working using the follow three lines of code.

```
Sub Test5440_2()

' copyWeek Macro

Range("B3").Copy
Sheets("History 5440").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

' Copy Laptop Info

Range("B8:E8").Copy Sheets("History 5440").Range("B1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

'Copy Last weeks

Sheets("History 5440").Range("F6").Copy Sheets("History 5440").Range("F1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
End Sub
```

This works just fine. But when I make copies of it to applie to other worksheets, it only does a partial copy. It works for the first two "History" tabs. after that it only copies the "laptop info" and not the week or lastweek.

Its a lot of lines for 3 tasks, so if there is a way to consolidate a few things to make it cleaner, I would love to figure it out. I think this is why it only works on the first two worksheets?

'Copy info for laptops and move to its history tab

```
Range("B8:e8").Copy Sheets("History 5440").Range("B1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

Range("B9:e9").Copy Sheets("History 7450").Range("B1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

Range("B10:e10").Copy Sheets("History 7470").Range("B1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

Range("B11:e11").Copy Sheets("History MBP 15 Retina").Range("B1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

Range("B12:e12").Copy Sheets("History MBP 13 Retina").Range("B1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

'Copy week and move to history

Range("B3").Copy
Sheets("History 5440").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Range("B3").Copy
Sheets("History 7450").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Range("B3").Copy
Sheets("History 7470").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Range("B3").Copy
Sheets("History MBP 15 Retina").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Range("B3").Copy
Sheets("History MBP 13 Retina").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

'Copy Last weeks

Sheets("History 5440").Range("F6").Copy Sheets("History 5440").Range("F1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

Sheets("History 5440").Range("F6").Copy Sheets("History 5440").Range("F1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

Sheets("History 5440").Range("F6").Copy Sheets("History 5440").Range("F1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

Sheets("History 5440").Range("F6").Copy Sheets("History 5440").Range("F1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

Sheets("History 5440").Range("F6").Copy Sheets("History 5440").Range("F1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
```

Comment: If you have some code already please edit your question to include the code. If you don't then it's unlikely anyone will be willing to write it from scratch - unfortunately we aren't a script writing service. If you could also put up an example of your data/ what you hope to see - screenshots are helpful too.

Comment: Hi Callum, Yeah I put up the question with the intent of adding more info, but then we had a network outage here at the office and I got dragged away. I have attached the code I have put together, and a screen shot of the Copy from location, and the To location.

Comment: I can get it to work sometimes when i run it, but it pastes it into random cells. That is the latest code I am using, and the only one I have gotten to actually do something somewhat properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("a2").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a2").Value
End Sub
```

This is generally a pretty easy thing to do :)

Comment: So I tried that,     here is the code 

Private Sub test5440()

' test5440 Macro

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Current Inventory").Range("B8:G8").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("History 5440").Range("B5:G5").Value

End Sub

Comment: I also recorded a macro from what I saw others doing in some youtube videos:
I also tried without Private at the top because that is how my recorded macro makes it. It looks like this:

Sub Test5440_2()
'
' Test5440_2 Macro
    Sheets("Current Inventory").Select
    Range("B8:G8").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("History 5440").Select
    ActiveCell.Select
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub

Comment: When I recorded that macro, I pasted the B8:G8 into cell B5 on History 5440. When I run the macro, it pastes it into D6. When ran a second time, it pasts it into D5.

Comment: So I can't edit my first comment, but when I tried your .Value code, it would move the cell data to an unknown location. Range B8:G8 would be cleared, and I don't know where it gets moved to...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve my wanted results by using the following:

```
Range("B8:G8").Copy Sheets("History 5440").Range("B1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
```

It may not be the most efficient, but it gets the job done. If you have a recommendation on how to improve it somehow, I would love to hear it!